# Curly Brackets Formatting Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been looking in the options of Netbeans, but I cannot find a way to change the default location of the curly brackets

```
public class foo {

}
```

to this

```
public class foo
{

}
```

Comment: You don't specify the language. I've re-tagged as Java, please edit the question yourself if it's wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look in `Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting`.

Ref: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic8932.html

Comment: it is really great, but how can I see the method by placing cursor to the closing bracket, since did so?