# java - netbeans- formatting - keep curly brackets on same line?

Tags: netbeans, formatting, curly-brackets

i would like to keep code like this (and use autoformat):

```
try { System.out.println("oh"); } catch(Exception e) {}
try { System.out.println("hey"); } catch(Exception e) {}
```

but netbeans reformats to this:

```
try {
    System.out.println("oh");
} catch (Exception e) {
}
try {
    System.out.println("hey");
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

is there any way to prevent this? to keep try/catch, or at least to keep {} on same line?

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274658/curly-brackets-formatting-netbeans) has the following answer:

Look in `Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting`

For further reference: 'http://forums.netbeans.org/topic8932.html'